# Is it worth becoming the 9th paradigm?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

On the final Epsilon program strangers and freaks mission, is it worth becoming the 9th paradigm or is it better to just steal and make off with the cash?
Is there anything to gain out of becoming the 9th paradigm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reward you get from delivering the money is a tractor.

Because of that, it is generally recommended to just take the money for yourself. Not only do you get a return on your previous investment, stealing the money also happens to be part of the gold medal requirements along with killing all Epsilon security guards pursuing you. Add to it the additional challenge and the satisfaction from getting revenge after all the nonsensical tasks given to you up to this point, it's not difficult to see why it's preferable to just keep the $2.1 million.

After the mission is done you will receive a text message whose content depends on whether you stole the money or not. Surprisingly, nothing else will happen even if you steal the money (no crazy followers trying to kill you from time to times either).

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you really enjoy playing Michael like a doofus.

The only reward you receive is a rusty tractor, compared with the $2 million you get for stealing the money. You also cannot get the gold medal completion if you deliver the money- both objectives require stealing it.

Comment: I guess I'm a doofus then...

Answer (score 0):

You can steal it afterwards to get the gold medal, also you might be able to use the tractor to unlock something somewhere with the space docker